# PHP code not displaying results of looped array

Tags: php, twitter

I am new to PHP and I'm trying to amend code from the tutorial "Build Your First Twitter App Using PHP in 8 Easy Steps" to use the Twitter search API rather than the status.  Previous iteration using

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($string);
echo "</pre>";
```

to display my results worked great.  However, I'm trying to adapt it to use the $foreach function used in the tutorial, but it only returns the headings.  Here is the full code (minus the access tokens)

```
<?php

require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

/** Add a title.  Specify Twitter API to be used. We are using search. Then specify fields and requestMethod, bring back 5 most popular**/
echo "<h2>Top 5 Tweets for Cloud Computing</h2>";
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$getfield = '?q=Cloud Computing&count=5&result_type=popular';
$requestMethod = 'GET';

/** Connect to the Twitter API**/
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
if($string["errors"][0]["message"] != "") {echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3><p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>".$string[errors][0]["message"]."</em></p>";exit();}

/* echo "<pre>";
print_r($string);
echo "</pre>"; */

foreach($string as $items)
     {
        echo "Time and Date of Tweet: ".$items['created_at']."<br />";
        echo "Tweet: ". $items['text']."<br />";
        echo "Tweeted by: ". $items['user']['name']."<br />";
        echo "Screen name: ". $items['user']['screen_name']."<br />";
        echo "Friends: ". $items['user']['friends_count']."<br /><hr />";
    }
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
I am new to PHP and I'm trying to amend code from the tutorial "Build Your First Twitter App Using PHP in 8 Easy Steps" to use the Twitter search API rather than the status.  Previous iteration using 

echo "<pre>";
print_r($string);
echo "</pre>";
```

to display my results worked great.  However, I'm trying to adapt it to use the $foreach function used in the tutorial, but it only returns the headings.  Here is the full code (minus the access tokens)

```
<?php

require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

/** Add a title.  Specify Twitter API to be used. We are using search. Then specify fields and requestMethod, bring back 5 most popular**/
echo "<h2>Top 5 Tweets for Cloud Computing</h2>";
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$getfield = '?q=Cloud Computing&count=5&result_type=popular';
$requestMethod = 'GET';

/** Connect to the Twitter API**/
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
if($string["errors"][0]["message"] != "") {echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3><p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>".$string[errors][0]["message"]."</em></p>";exit();}

/* echo "<pre>";
print_r($string);
echo "</pre>"; */

foreach($string as $items)
     {
        echo "Time and Date of Tweet: ".$items['created_at']."<br />";
        echo "Tweet: ". $items['text']."<br />";
        echo "Tweeted by: ". $items['user']['name']."<br />";
        echo "Screen name: ". $items['user']['screen_name']."<br />";
        echo "Friends: ". $items['user']['friends_count']."<br /><hr />";
    }
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
I am new to PHP and I'm trying to amend code from the tutorial "Build Your First Twitter App Using PHP in 8 Easy Steps" to use the Twitter search API rather than the status.  Previous iteration using 

echo "<pre>";
print_r($string);
echo "</pre>";
```

to display my results worked great.  However, I'm trying to adapt it to use the $foreach function used in the tutorial, but it only returns the headings.  Here is the full code (minus the access tokens)

```
<?php

require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

/** Add a title.  Specify Twitter API to be used. We are using search. Then specify fields and requestMethod, bring back 5 most popular**/
echo "<h2>Top 5 Tweets for Cloud Computing</h2>";
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$getfield = '?q=Cloud Computing&count=5&result_type=popular';
$requestMethod = 'GET';

/** Connect to the Twitter API**/
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
if($string["errors"][0]["message"] != "") {echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3><p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>".$string[errors][0]["message"]."</em></p>";exit();}

/* echo "<pre>";
print_r($string);
echo "</pre>"; */

foreach($string as $items)
     {
        echo "Time and Date of Tweet: ".$items['created_at']."<br />";
        echo "Tweet: ". $items['text']."<br />";
        echo "Tweeted by: ". $items['user']['name']."<br />";
        echo "Screen name: ". $items['user']['screen_name']."<br />";
        echo "Friends: ". $items['user']['friends_count']."<br /><hr />";
    }
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
Top 5 Tweets for Cloud Computing
Array
(
    [statuses] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [created_at] => Tue Apr 10 19:50:32 +0000 2018
                    [id] => 983794376915726343
                    [id_str] => 983794376915726343
                    [text] => Forget "Old man yells at cloud." Now it's, "Old man yells at cloud computing."
                    [truncated] => 
                    [entities] => Array
                        (
                            [hashtags] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [symbols] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [user_mentions] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [urls] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [metadata] => Array
                        (
                            [result_type] => popular
                            [iso_language_code] => en
                        )

                    [source] => Twitter Web Client
                    [in_reply_to_status_id] => 983790713132503040
                    [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => 983790713132503040
                    [in_reply_to_user_id] => 155581583
                    [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 155581583
                    [in_reply_to_screen_name] => robbysoave
                    [user] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 155581583
                            [id_str] => 155581583
                            [name] => Robby Soave
                            [screen_name] => robbysoave
                            [location] => 
                            [description] => @reason editor. @thedailybeast columnist. 2016 @forbes 30 Under 30 list. @TFASorg Novak Fellow. Currently writing a book about activism in the age of Trump.
                            [url] => 
                            [entities] => Array
                                (
                                    [url] => Array
                                        (
                                            [urls] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [url] => 
                                                            [expanded_url] => http://reason.com
                                                            [display_url] => reason.com
                                                            [indices] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => 0
                                                                    [1] => 23
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [description] => Array
                                        (
                                            [urls] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [protected] => 
                            [followers_count] => 16817
                            [friends_count] => 1174
                            [listed_count] => 463
                            [created_at] => Mon Jun 14 14:45:39 +0000 2010
                            [favourites_count] => 4190
                            [utc_offset] => -14400
                            [time_zone] => Eastern Time (US & Canada)
                            [geo_enabled] => 1
                            [verified] => 1
                            [statuses_count] => 20014
                            [lang] => en
                            [contributors_enabled] => 
                            [is_translator] => 
                            [is_translation_enabled] => 
                            [profile_background_color] => 022330
                            [profile_link_color] => 0084B4
                            [profile_sidebar_border_color] => A8C7F7
                            [profile_sidebar_fill_color] => C0DFEC
                            [profile_text_color] => 333333
                            [profile_use_background_image] => 1
                            [has_extended_profile] => 1
                            [default_profile] => 
                            [default_profile_image] => 
                            [following] => 
                            [follow_request_sent] => 
                            [notifications] => 
                            [translator_type] => none
                        )

                    [geo] => 
                    [coordinates] => 
                    [place] => 
                    [contributors] => 
                    [is_quote_status] => 
                    [retweet_count] => 260
                    [favorite_count] => 1363
                    [favorited] => 
                    [retweeted] => 
                    [lang] => en
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [created_at] => Tue Apr 10 11:00:01 +0000 2018
                    [id] => 983660869904228352
                    [id_str] => 983660869904228352
                    [text] => Google can now use cloud computing, geo-mapping and machine learning to prevent illegal fishing… 
                    [truncated] => 1
                    [entities] => Array
                        (
                            [hashtags] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [symbols] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [user_mentions] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [urls] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => 
                                            [expanded_url] => https://twitter.com/i/web/status/983660869904228352
                                            [display_url] => twitter.com/i/web/status/9…
                                            [indices] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => 97
                                                    [1] => 120
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [metadata] => Array
                        (
                            [result_type] => popular
                            [iso_language_code] => en
                        )

                    [source] => Sprinklr
                    [in_reply_to_status_id] => 
                    [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => 
                    [in_reply_to_user_id] => 
                    [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 
                    [in_reply_to_screen_name] => 
                    [user] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 91478624
                            [id_str] => 91478624
                            [name] => Forbes
                            [screen_name] => Forbes
                            [location] => New York, NY
                            [description] => Official Twitter account of ?? homepage for the world's business leaders.
                            [url] => 
                            [entities] => Array
                                (
                                    [url] => Array
                                        (
                                            [urls] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [url] => 
                                                            [expanded_url] => http://forbes.com
                                                            [display_url] => forbes.com
                                                            [indices] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => 0
                                                                    [1] => 22
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [description] => Array
                                        (
                                            [urls] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [url] => 
                                                            [expanded_url] => http://Forbes.com
                                                            [display_url] => Forbes.com
                                                            [indices] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => 28
                                                                    [1] => 48
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [protected] => 
                            [followers_count] => 14757421
                            [friends_count] => 5712
                            [listed_count] => 54795
                            [created_at] => Sat Nov 21 02:09:57 +0000 2009
                            [favourites_count] => 8639
                            [utc_offset] => -14400
                            [time_zone] => Eastern Time (US & Canada)
                            [geo_enabled] => 
                            [verified] => 1
                            [statuses_count] => 179200
                            [lang] => en
                            [contributors_enabled] => 
                            [is_translator] => 
                            [is_translation_enabled] => 1
                            [profile_background_color] => 072250
                            [profile_background_image_url] => http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/457626324/twitter_background_dark3.png
                            [profile_background_image_url_https] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/457626324/twitter_background_dark3.png
                            [profile_background_tile] => 
                            [profile_image_url] => http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/882603270484766720/YFx4Lsh4_normal.jpg
                            [profile_image_url_https] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/882603270484766720/YFx4Lsh4_normal.jpg
                            [profile_banner_url] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/91478624/1514830219
                            [profile_link_color] => 072250
                            [profile_sidebar_border_color] => CCCCCC
                            [profile_sidebar_fill_color] => F7F7F7
                            [profile_text_color] => 000000
                            [profile_use_background_image] => 1
                            [has_extended_profile] => 
                            [default_profile] => 
                            [default_profile_image] => 
                            [following] => 
                            [follow_request_sent] => 
                            [notifications] => 
                            [translator_type] => regular
                        )

                    [geo] => 
                    [coordinates] => 
                    [place] => 
                    [contributors] => 
                    [is_quote_status] => 
                    [retweet_count] => 48
                    [favorite_count] => 100
                    [favorited] => 
                    [retweeted] => 
                    [possibly_sensitive] => 
                    [lang] => en
                )
```

Comment: Can you show the results of `print_r($string);` so we can see the array? Edit your post and paste it at the bottom.

Comment: "it only returns the headings"  What headings?

Comment: Wow!  You guys are fast :-)  for headings I mean the "Time and Date of Tweet" etc. in the foreach loop.

Comment: Will post results of print_r($string); in a second, thanks.  Now posted.

Comment: If that's the case, then you should probably be getting "undefined index" errors.  Make sure you have error reporting turned on.

Comment: _"Now posted"_ - Don't know if it's just me, but I don't see any edits on the question?

Comment: @Jac You don't seem to have updated your code with the result of `print_r( $string )`. We cannot help you further if you don't provide us with this information.

Comment: There's lots of URL references the Stackoverflow editor isn't happy with, I'm trying to remove them all so I can add results as requested.

Comment: That should be it now.  Apologies for the delay.

Comment: Everything you want appears to be within a `statuses` sub-array.  You need to `foreach` within _that_.

Comment: @PatrickQ - thanks, but this is my first piece of PHP code so I'm not sure how I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data that you want appears to be one level further into the array than you are currently going.  Specifically, the data is within a `statuses` sub-array.  You simply need to run your `foreach` at *that* level instead of the top level.

```
foreach($string['statuses'] as $items)
 {
    echo "Time and Date of Tweet: ".$items['created_at']."<br />";
    echo "Tweet: ". $items['text']."<br />";
    echo "Tweeted by: ". $items['user']['name']."<br />";
    echo "Screen name: ". $items['user']['screen_name']."<br />";
    echo "Friends: ". $items['user']['friends_count']."<br /><hr />";
}
```

Comment: you are a star!  I got the lower level of the array, just wasn't sure how to get there.  That has worked a treat, I can't thank you enough. My first experience posting on Stack has been a good one!  I have voted, but it does not count being my first time here.

Comment: @Jac Glad to help.  For being your first time here, you had a reasonably well-asked (if basic) question once you provided the additional information.  More than can be said for most people here.  So kudos.

Answer (score -2):

maybe try in your foreach loop this

```
foreach($string as $items => $value)
```

Comment: Do you want to give an explanation as to why?

Comment: How would this help if the OP only care about the values anyway? The only thing this would do is to force the OP to change `$items` to `$value` everywhere in the loop.

Comment: This did not work, I got an entry 'S' for each field.

Comment: cause at the beginning of the post they have no explanation about the entire of the code and result post are just updated with the full code easy to say How would this help if the OP only care about the values anyway